# numbers in HTML component

Tags: node.js, angular

Hi I create team (It works), but I want to calculate prices. When you choose player (his price is available), I want to subtract from default price. So default price is 100 and if you choose player who cost 5, angular calculate to 95 and then send to database.
extract of HTML of one player:

```
  <mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="Goalkeepers" formControlName="goalkeeper">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let player of goalkeepers" [value]="player.id">
         {{player.name}} {{player.surename}} ({{player.price}}M)
  </mat-option>

</mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('goalkeeper').invalid">Pleasse enter a goalkeeper.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

And than I have badget of team:

```
<p *ngFor="let userTeam of userTeamDetails">
    <span *ngIf="userTeam.badget">
     Tvoje dostupne peniaze: {{userTeam.badget}}M €
    </span>
  </p>
```

I tried to make {{userTeam.badget - player.price}}, but userTeam was not known and I don´t want to see in every player price.

What possibilities I have to calculate this? I don´t have any idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-container` in conjunction with `ngIf` to conditionally display the calculated price only when the team and its budget exists. Example:

```html
<mat-option *ngFor="let player of goalkeepers" [value]="player.id">
  {{player.name}} {{player.surename}} ({{player.price}}M)
  <ng-container *ngIf="userTeam?.badget">{{userTeam.badget - player.price}}</ng-container>
</mat-option>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Yes, it works, but only for goalkeeper. But if I have three inputs mat-options for players, than I calculate badget only for one player. So If I select first Goalkeeper, I got 100 (it is badget) - priceOfGoalkeeper. And than I have defender, and I got again 100 - price ... But I need one badget for all. If I choose in three inputs three players, than I got 100 - first player - second player - third player price. How can I do it?

Comment: I would keep a `totalPrice` variable and each time a player is added/dropped you subtract or add from the total respectively and then subtract that amount from the team budget.

Comment: Please, can you give me any example how can I create it ?

Comment: Please create a stackblitz for me to look at to better understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Of course, here is link on this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfijs3 
But it is not working on stackblitz, because I have a lot connections, but here is this part, what about we say and I need with help and in first goalkeeper I tried your first help. But you can see it in code